# Understanding voltage in AC

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

With DC, for example, a battery, it's easy to understand that one terminal is more negatively charged then the other, so that there is a potential difference between the terminals, which creates a voltage between them, so that if we connect a conductive material, current will flow.

It's harder for me to understand the concept of voltage when we talk about AC. Let's take this image for example, taken from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mc979OhitAg&list=PLWv9VM947MKi_7yJ0_FCfzTBXpQU-Qd3K):

[image]

So there is a coil, and inside it there is a magnet moving back and forth, which causes electrons to move in the circuit.

This doesn't quite fit in the model of electric potential difference. How is voltage measured in this model?

Also, we know that in a typical household power system there is a hot and neutral wires. According to this image, AC electricity is basically a closed loop in which electricity flows back and forth, so why is the hot called 'hot' and the neutral 'neutral'? I can't see any difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

> This doesn't quite fit in the model of electric potential difference. How is voltage measured in this model?

The same way as before, but it varies over time.  You could disconnect the coil from the circuit and hook it up to the same voltmeter you used on the battery.  You would see the voltage difference on the coil swing back and forth.  But instead of showing the peak differences, most AC voltmeters will display the root mean square difference.

> Also, we know that in a typical household power system there is a hot and neutral wires. According to this image, AC electricity is basically a closed loop in which electricity flows back and forth, so why is the hot called 'hot' and the neutral 'neutral'? I can't see any difference between them?

To the circuit, there is no difference.  The load is just using the voltage difference to draw power.

But for various reasons including safety, we arbitrarily pick one side of the supply and tie it to ground.  This side is often called the "neutral" in everyday language.  When this is done, the circuit behaves the same as it did before.  But now when everything is operating properly, one conductor is the same potential as the ground.  If that conductor were to make contact with something else that is also at ground potential, it shouldn't be dangerous.

Comment: _You could disconnect the coil from the circuit_ - what coil? The one on the right?

Comment: _we arbitrarily pick one side and tie it to ground_ - you mean, physically tie it to the ground? and then what? it always balances with the electric potential of ground?

Comment: The actual way this is done differs from place to place, but yes.  One side is fixed to ground, so the other side has a potential relative to ground.

Comment: No, I was talking about disconnecting the power coil (the one described in the question).  If the magnet is moved through it and it is not part of a circuit (or just has a voltmeter attached), it will develop a voltage.

You could attach the voltmeter to the full circuit as well, but the behavior might be different than just measuring the voltage source.

Comment: You mean, if you break the circuit and keep moving the magnet in the coil, then we will have a voltage?

Comment: Yep.  The field changes induce a voltage in the coil.  That voltage can be directly read with a voltmeter, or it can do work when attached to a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of voltage differences is fine even in the AC case. It is the amount of energy you can extract if you move an electron from one location to another at that time.

But you yourself worded your problem out: you are insisting that voltages must always be considered as due to the electric potential. This is wrong. Watch Veritasium on what carries energy in electrical circuits, and Lewin's lectures, on this topic.

That is, if you repeatedly charge and discharge a capacitor to force an AC voltage, yes, you can use electric potential to do all these things and you can make sense of them. However, when you are using the magnets to generate the AC waveform, your AC is coming from Faraday's law, and that is a non-conservative force field. There is no way to uniquely define an electric potential once that is happening.

The energy is not being carried by each electron. The energy is being carried by E and B fields, mostly outside the wires. And then because we cannot be expecting every electrical engineer to be learning such abstruse knowledge, we figure out many approximate methods for electrical engineers to make do without such a deep understanding. We teach them that, and then they make video rebuttals to the correct answer.

Anyway, back to the question. BowlOfRed is correct that one side of the circuit will be forcibly grounded, so that that one is neutral and the other one is hot. Electrical energy can only be extracted when you connect the hot wire to any grounded wire, using the difference to extract the energy.

Note that we are so lazy to work with new equations, that we have deliberately defined a lot of stuff to fit the DC case. That is, in the DC case, the voltage and current are simple, as is the resistance, and you can have Ohm's law $V=IR$. If you scrutinise the definition of voltage and current, you see that by definition power $P=IV$, and you get the other forms by substituting Ohm's law into that. In the AC case, we are supposed to do time averaging of these, and that is just too tedious. We prove that in the sinusoidal case, using RMS voltage and current, the AC formulæ will become exactly the same as the DC ones, and so that is what we actually do and define them to be.

This is important because once we get the power to agree, then we can use AC voltages and currents the same way we use resistive heating in the DC case, and that is one possible way to measure voltages and currents, by precisely calibrated pure resistances and thermometry. Nobody practically does this, but in principle it can be done like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Build** that circuit, drive it by an AC volatage, plug an oscilloscope to it, i.e. the voltage difference between two points, synchronize time and read the curves. Notice e.g. time variation, peak values, phase shifts, frequency dependence.

Pick a book which introduces into **electric networks**, not into electronic circuits. At best it talks about rotating vectors, effective values, impedances, frequency dependence. At least it works with complex numbers. Perhaps it gives an outlook into Laplace transformation. If not, it should give you an idea about the equivalence of observations in time and in frequency. It should tell you all about how to perform and evaluate calculations for simple networks, like the one above.

If you want to **confine** yourself to "what you can or can't imagine", physics may not be your place. It's more about describing in a consistent and logical way observations based on a few theorems *(like: "if I do A and B, then C has to follow and vice versa, C requires A and B being in place")*. In this respect it's closer to mathematics.